# In druid how to copy metric data from one dataSource to another?

Tags: druid

I have metric data for time period 20150101 to 20160101 in druid dataSource "D1". Is it possible to copy a subset of this metric day for a time period 20150601-20160101 to another data source "D2" in druid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can reindex your data from an existing data source (Delta ingestion mode)
Please read this
[delta ingestion docs](http://druid.io/docs/latest/ingestion/update-existing-data.html#reindexing-and-delta-ingestion-with-hadoop-batch-ingestion)